# How can one obtain the "name" of a process start address as done in Process Explorer?

Tags: c++, windows, process, kernel

Okay, I'm writing an application designed to enumerate threads in a given process, just as Process Explorer does. I'm well aware that this is potentially going to break between different windows versions, because it relies on "unofficial" APIs like `NtQuerySystemInformation`, and I'm perfectly fine with that.

I already have the code to obtain the base address of a given thread. I'd like to now turn that into something like what process explorer does, i.e. "ntdll.dll!EtwDeliverDataBlock+0x453". I don't actually need the function name or offset, just the module name.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is the module name, the simplest way is to use [EnumProcessModules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682631.aspx) to get a list of all the loaded the modules, then use [GetModuleInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683201.aspx) on each of them. One of the things that `GetModuleInformation` returns is the base address where that module is loaded. Technically, the integer value of the `HMODULE` itself is the same as the base address, but that seems a little fragile to me...

Then it's simply a matter of finding the module with a base address just below the thread's current (or start) address.

Oh, and to get the actual name of the module, there's [GetModuleBaseName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683196.aspx).

Comment: Hmm.. this might work. Is there any way to do it such that I don't have to actually open a handle to the target process? (can't do that to the system process, for example)

Comment: @Billy: I'm not sure. I believe Process Explorer actually uses a kernel-mode driver for some of it's features, so maybe this is one of those times..?

Comment: Working around it by calling NtQuerySystemInformation with the class `SystemModuleInformation` -- I'll get back to you with what I come up with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**GetModuleHandleEx**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683200.aspx) with the `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` flag to get a handle to a module given an address. You can then use [**GetModuleBaseName**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683196.aspx) to get the name of the module.

**Edit:** You'll probably want to use the `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT` flag as well, so you don't increase the reference count of the module.

Comment: GetModuleHandleEx doesn't work for remote processes. Because of this your suggestion to use the `UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT` flag is irrelevant as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can use that code to get module handle (it is faster than [**GetModuleHandleEx**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683200.aspx)) and then call [**GetModuleBaseName**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683196.aspx).

```
HMODULE GetCallingModule( LPCVOID pCaller ) const
{
    HMODULE hModule = NULL;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    if ( VirtualQuery(pCaller, &mbi, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)) == sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION) )
    {
        // the allocation base is the beginning of a PE file 
        hModule = (HMODULE) mbi.AllocationBase;
    }
    return hModule;
}
```

Comment: @KindDragon: it requires `VirtualQueryEx` to work across processes and even then requires the respective process handle. It's a neat trick, though, to get `HINSTANCE hInstance` by looking up the `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION::AllocationBase` of a static variable in your own process. But that's only ever needed if you avoid boilerplate CRT code or so ...